# PYTHON - multiprocessing pipe(), receive last sent (most recent data)

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

when using python multiprocessing pipe for this example, the sending end is continually sending data every 1 second.  The receiving end reads every 4 seconds.  How can I "empty" the pipe and recv() the last entry?  Thanks.
Currently the output is as follows:

Sender: Running
Receiver: Running
Sender sent  1
**>receiver got 1**
Sender sent  2
Sender sent  3
Sender sent  4
**>receiver got 2**
Sender sent  5
Sender sent  6
Sender sent  7
Sender sent  8
**>receiver got 3**
Sender sent  9
Sender sent  10
Sender sent  11
Sender sent  12
**>receiver got 4**
etc

But I would like it to be:

Sender: Running
Receiver: Running
Sender sent  1
**>receiver got 1**
Sender sent  2
Sender sent  3
Sender sent  4
**>receiver got 4**
Sender sent  5
Sender sent  6
Sender sent  7
Sender sent  8
**>receiver got 8**
Sender sent  9
Sender sent  10
Sender sent  11
Sender sent  12
**>receiver got 12**
etc

And the code is:

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pipe
 
# generate work
def sender(connection):
    print('Sender: Running', flush=True)
    # generate work
    for i in range(1000):
        # generate a value
        value = i + 1
        # block
        sleep(1)
        # send data
        connection.send(value)
        print("Sender sent ",value)
    # all done
    connection.send(None)
    print('Sender: Done', flush=True)
 
# consume work
def receiver(connection):
    print('Receiver: Running', flush=True)
    # consume work
    while True:
        # get a unit of work
        item = connection.recv()
        # report
        print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
        sleep(4)
        if item is None:
            break
    # all done
    print('Receiver: Done', flush=True)
 
# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the pipe
    conn1, conn2 = Pipe()
    # start the sender
    sender_process = Process(target=sender, args=(conn2,))
    sender_process.start()
    # start the receiver
    receiver_process = Process(target=receiver, args=(conn1,))
    receiver_process.start()
    # wait for all processes to finish
    sender_process.join()
    receiver_process.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I tried using a while statement with poll() and the output works.  If there is a better more efficient solution I'd love to hear it.

```
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pipe
 
# generate work
def sender(connection):
    print('Sender: Running', flush=True)
    # generate work
    for i in range(1000):
        # generate a value
        value = i + 1
        # block
        sleep(1)
        # send data
        connection.send(value)
        print("Sender sent ",value)
    # all done
    connection.send(None)
    print('Sender: Done', flush=True)
 
# consume work
def receiver(connection):
    print('Receiver: Running', flush=True)
    # consume work
    while True:
        # get a unit of work
        item = connection.recv()
        while connection.poll():
            item = connection.recv()
        # report
        print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
        sleep(4)
        if item is None:
            break
    # all done
    print('Receiver: Done', flush=True)
 
# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the pipe
    conn1, conn2 = Pipe()
    # start the sender
    sender_process = Process(target=sender, args=(conn2,))
    sender_process.start()
    # start the receiver
    receiver_process = Process(target=receiver, args=(conn1,))
    receiver_process.start()
    # wait for all processes to finish
    sender_process.join()
    receiver_process.join()
```

Comment: I don't think this solution is actually great.  It would be better to clear the pipe before sending (ie keep iterating on the send side - clearing and sending latest.  I'm not sure if this is possible though?

Answer (score 0):

In your reader's `while` loop, you are potentially getting more than one item on each iteration but only testing for `None` on the last item.  You need to test every item received for `None`:

```py
...

# consume work
def receiver(connection):
    print('Receiver: Running', flush=True)
    # consume work
    while True:
        # get a unit of work
        item = connection.recv()
        print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
        while connection.poll():
            item = connection.recv()
            if item is None:
                break
            print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
        if item is None:
            break
        sleep(4)
    # all done
    print('Receiver: Done', flush=True)
...
```

There still remains a problem with this code: A Pipe has a limited capacity and a writer will eventually block once that capacity is reached. Since the reader will not be receiving for 4 seconds, the writer needs the pipe to have at least a capacity of at least 4 for it to not block. But does it have that capacity? I don't know and can we depend on this value? So perhaps you should use a `multiprocessing.Queue`. But remember, testing for an empty queue by calling method `empty` is not "reliable" according to the documenttaion. So we *could* do a non-blocking call, which could possibly get an exception:

```py
from time import sleep
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Queue
from queue import Empty

# generate work
def sender(queue):
    print('Sender: Running', flush=True)
    # generate work
    for i in range(1000):
        # generate a value
        value = i + 1
        # block
        sleep(1)
        # send data
        queue.put(value)
        print("Sender sent ",value)
    # all done
    queue.put(None)
    print('Sender: Done', flush=True)

# consume work
def receiver(queue):
    print('Receiver: Running', flush=True)
    # consume work
    while True:
        # get a unit of work
        # This is a blocking get:
        item = queue.get()
        print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
        # Now do non-blocking gets:
        try:
            while True:
                item = queue.get_nowait()
                if item is None:
                    break
                print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
        except Empty:
            pass
        if item is None:
            break
        sleep(4)
    # all done
    print('Receiver: Done', flush=True)

# entry point
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create the pipe
    queue = Queue()
    # start the sender
    sender_process = Process(target=sender, args=(queue,))
    sender_process.start()
    # start the receiver
    receiver_process = Process(target=receiver, args=(queue,))
    receiver_process.start()
    # wait for all processes to finish
    sender_process.join()
    receiver_process.join()
```

Even thought method `empty` is not considered reliable, it probably is "reliable enough" for our purposes in that if it return False, there will be at least one readable message. If it return True, there could potentially be a message that has already been put to the queue but has not ended up on it yet (the `put` call is processed by a thread that is doing sends to the underlying pipe). But that should not be a serious issue. So we can simplify the receiver:

```py
# consume work
def receiver(queue):
    print('Receiver: Running', flush=True)
    # consume work
    while True:
        # get a unit of work
        # This is a blocking get:
        item = queue.get()
        print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
        # Now do non-blocking gets:
        while not queue.empty():
            item = queue.get_nowait()
            if item is None:
                break
            print(f'>receiver got {item}', flush=True)
        if item is None:
            break
        sleep(4)
    # all done
    print('Receiver: Done', flush=True)
```